# PHPExcel create file with writing mode

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I create an Excel file with writing mode using PHP-Excel library

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Item Report');
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    header('Content-type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Vendor Report-'.date('d-m-Y').'.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Please be a little bit more specific, Could you tell us what your results are?

Comment: What `crerte file` no Idea what that is.

Comment: its spelling mistake .. its 'create file'

Comment: You could try google, first maybe .. found this looking at the documentation https://dannyherran.com/2011/03/exporting-your-mysql-table-data-with-phpexcel-codeigniter/  And this https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/FAQ

Comment: Setting the content type to `text/csv` and then using the Excel5 Writer rather than the CSV Writer is a bad start.... you're already creating a discrepancy between what you're telling the browser that you're goig to write, and what you're actually writing

Comment: One question, is excel necessary or will a simple CSV format work,  The problem with the execl format `xls, xlsx` is that you have to open the entire file, this is fine for small files but for large files big problems, we dropped support for excel files at my work, but we deal with millions of rows sometimes.  With a simple CSV file it can be processed per line avoiding memory issues.

Comment: But `not able to edit downloaded file`.... what does that mean? Does it download a file or not? Does it download a wrong file? Does it write any errors to the logs or the screen? Does the server eat your pet hamster or spontaneously combust?

Comment: can you clear my code. what to change in code???

Comment: I had a server spontaneously combustion, it was brand new,  cooked the raid controller after importing 200GB of MySQL data... sucked. and it was a rack server, not some junk.  54GB ram. 12 cores.

Comment: "not able to edit downloaded file" no its downloading but when i open it .. its now allowing me to edit data

Comment: You are aware that MS Excel blocks editing on files downloaded from web sites (protected view) unless you tell MS Excel that you want to enable editing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes i got a solution. Save as file then after you can edit it...